# How to fetch all to many items from a specific Core Data parent entity ID

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, entity, fetch

I am pretty new to this and assume I am missing something very simple, I have tried this site and anywhere I could search but found no straightforward answer.

My situation..

- My model can have many Calisthenic Entities which can of course contain many sets.
- I have a calisthenic detail controller which uses a fetch request to pull all the sets data and display it.  With the code below my detail view works fine.
- The problem is, if I create and enter another calisthenic detail view my fetch of course pulls all the Set entities from all the calisthenic entities, I of course only want to pull the sets for the calisthenic ID I am interacting with.

So how to I pull all the sets related to 1 calisthenic ID in my fetch request?

```
- (void)fetchSets
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Set"];
    NSString *cacheName = [@"Set" stringByAppendingString:@"Cache"];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"setNumber" ascending:YES];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.calisthenic.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:cacheName];

    NSError *error;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Fetch failed: %@", error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use NSPredicate to filter the fetch request based on the parent object which is the Calisthenic.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"calisthenic == %@", calisthenic]
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

The line above assumes the property of the parent is called calisthenic.

Or if you have created model files (the subclasses of NSManagedObject) for Calisthenic and Sets, you can simply take the parent calisthenic object and get the sets directly.

```
calisthenic.sets
```

in which NSSet is returned.

Take a look at the following tutorial on how to generate model files: [Getting started with Core Data](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started)

Comment: Thank you very much, you made my day and probably my week.  I had been playing with other predicates with ID, and such and just couldn't make anything work right. lack of experience I knew I was missing something simple.   The predicate worked perfect and gave me the desired result.     I would up-vote and such but I'm brand new here and apparently don't have the reputation lol :)